# qlikview table filter forcing wrong filter

Tags: sql-server, expression, qlikview

Using qlikview 8 personnel edition.

On my main tab i have a chart that concats year and period (year and month) from this I use it as a filter to select periods, this works fine except when trying to select multiple years and periods, it allows selection but say:

Select all from year 2013, and up to year 2014 month 09.  It actually selects all from 2013 and 2014.

why would it be doing this?

Some details:

```
=Num#(If(Len(Year & Period)=5,Year & '0' & Period, Year & Period))
```

outputs "201301" etc

Like I said i can select whatever month upto a month i want withing a year.  However doing the same over multiple years forces it to select all months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the year & month columns are separate in your model, making the selection that you described actually *DID* select all of the months. You got them from 2013. It didn't care that you only hoped to limit to 1-9 for 2014.

If possible, move that concatenation to the load script where it can become its own field and then you should be good to go.